# Which Django model relationship is appropriate?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I create a Profile extending the Django User Model, each time a new user is created.

And I want to store multiple items in a field, for example, 10 track names in the track name field for a particular user, in the Profile(will differ from user to user). Which model relationship can help achieve this? Or do I create a new model for songs, named preferably "songs", and use a model relationship to Profile? What is the best way to do this?

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Meta:
    db_table = "Profile"

class Liked_Songs(models.Model):
     track_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, 
     related_name=tracks),
     artiste_name= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, 
      related_name=artiste),
      album_name =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, 
       related_name=albums)
class Meta:
    db_table = "Profile"

def __str__(self):
    return self.track_name
```

EDIT:

```
>>> from comparison.models import Album, Song, UserProfile
>>> song = Song.objects.all().values_list("pk", flat=True)
>>> song
<QuerySet [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> song = Song.objects.get(pk=66)
>>> song
<Song: Every Day I Love You Less and Less>
>>> song.users_that_liked_me.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> `
```

But when I check my database, it shows certain user profiles have users who have liked songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely let's create a `songs` table:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    liked_songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', ..., related_name='users_that_liked_me')

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', ..., related_name='songs')
```

What's going on here?

One `Album` can have many `Song`s, but a `Song` can only have a single `Album`.

We can do something like:

```
album = Album.objects.get(id=<the-album-id>)
songs_on_the_album = album.songs.all()
```

A `User` can like many `Song`s and a `Song` can be liked by many `User`s:

```
song = Song.objects.get(id=<the-song-id>)
users_that_liked_this_song = song.users_that_liked_me.all()
```

Depending on your relationships, you may either want a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Thank you. Quick question. How do I send data to the `album ForeignKey` in the `Song` model? , essentially the `title` field in the `Album` model

Comment: Adding an album to a song: `song.album = <the-album-instance>` - adding a song to an album: `album.songs.add([<song-instance-1>, <song-instance-2>', ...])` - don't forget to save you song / album after updating it.